# Flash air compatibility with iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, flash, air

I'm about to start developing a mobile app and I'm wondering whether flash can be packaged with apps in both iOS and Android? Are there any implications to be aware of (such as iOS version compatibility?)

Comment: No, you can't embed flash to iOS apps.

Comment: yes you can, Adobe air allows you to package a flash app as an IOS or Android app https://get.adobe.com/air/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main selling points of using the Adobe AIR SDK in Flash is to allow 'packaging' of apps for multiple platforms, including iOS and Android. You'll have to publish separately, of course, to get .ipa files and .apks, but one code-base gets you to both mobile platforms. I've had no trouble with iOS compatibility between all versions from 4.3 to 7. Depending on what you're trying to do you may want to incorporate ANEs -- Adobe Native Extensions -- which require some programming in native codes (Objective C or Java) to get some types of native functionality. I tend to use outside help for that.